# Flutter: How do I get List<String> from the JSON response?

Tags: json, string

I want to do feature  follow this https://amazevlley.blogspot.com/2019/03/listview-sort-by-name-in-flutter.html in my application but I can't get the List< String> from this function.

```
Future<String> getJSONData() async {
var url = "http://.......:7000/";

// Await the http get response, then decode the json-formatted response.
var response = await http.get(url);

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  var jsonResponse = json.decode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes));

  setState(() {
    data = jsonResponse['data'];
  });

  print('jsonResponse: $jsonResponse.');
} else {
  print('Request failed with status: ${response.statusCode}.');
}}
```